# How did my question in 1 day get so many views when there are so many inactive people on the website?

Tags: discussion, bug

[Question Link](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/136912/is-it-harmful-for-seo-to-repeat-the-same-call-to-action-at-the-bottom-of-every-p)

I asked a question yesterday and when I looked at the screen of my question today, I saw that it was displayed a lot.

If this question got this many views, the other questions should get an average view. But there is a big difference between them and my question.

My question is, is this a bug? do moderators have a chance to check?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was featured in the [Hot Network Questions](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot) which highlights popular questions on all SE sites. When featured there it will drive additional traffic to a question.

[image]

Comment: I understood thank you. Are moderators choosing this popular question?

Comment: @ardacar The question gets chosen automatically by Stack Exchange once it gets a high enough ["hotness score"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/299116). Moderators [have the ability to remove, but not choose, a hot network question.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325060/updating-the-hot-network-questions-list-now-with-a-bit-more-network-and-a-litt)